# Creating a DataFrame in one function and using it in another function

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently loading in a CSV file and displaying that CSV file to a LabelFrame

On a different LabelFrame I have a "mean" button to calculate the mean of the data. However I am getting this error

`NameError: name 'df' is not defined`

I have a DataFrame that I created in a function called load_data() that outputs the data to the LabelFrame. My next objective is to press the "mean" button and have it calculate the mean. I figured maybe it was not working because that variable isn't global. However, I did this:

```
 `def compute_mean():
       global df
       calcMean = df.mean()`
```

df is being used in my load_data() function as follows:

```
 `df = pd.read_csv(filename)`
```

Comment: use a parameter to feed in your `df`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try avoiding globals. Pass the dataframe to your function instead.

```
def compute_mean(df):
    return df.mean()

df = pd.read_csv(filename)

mean = compute_mean(df)
```

Of course, in this case, the function is just a wrapper to df.mean(), so it can be avoided.

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
mean = df.mean()
```

If you have a `load_data()` function, then be sure it returns the dataframe.

```
def load_data(filename):
    return pd.read_csv(filename)

df = load_data(filename)
mean = df.mean()
```

Comment: I don't mean to make a big deal out of this, but I think to better convey how people actually view the OPs approach to globals would be sentences like: "Avoid using globals";  "Using globals like you have is highly discouraged because it makes your code hard to follow and maintain (as you have found)"; "It's not just a Python thing, but using globals like this is poor practice in any programming language"'. That sort of thing. The questioner is clearly a beginner, so it seems to me that it would be helpful to set a clear context about using globals in this way.

Comment: @tom10 you are completely right. I rushed the answer ending up being dry. I tend to do that. Thanks for pointing it out and for the comment. I'll mind that next time.

Answer (score 0):

Did you return `df` in you `load_data` function? Something like this:

```
def load_data(filename):
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    return df
```

Then you use `load_data` function inside `compute_mean`, here `df` is assigned to `x`:

```
def compute_mean(somefile):
    x = load_data(somefile)
    calcMean = x.mean()
    return calcMean
```

Comment: `somefile` should be passed to `compute_mean()`